# Using days of the week for aggregates in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I currently have a query that reads from a table which is written to daily, so I have totals for every day.

What I'm trying to do is modify this query so that I can use days of the week as an aggregate, if that makes sense.

THe totals I get right now are correct, but I want to use Sunday through Saturday as a week and effectively say ``'If today is wednesday, sum totals for weeklyData for Sunday, MOnday and Tuesday from tableOne```

I have this query:

```
SELECT employee,
   sum(case when category = 'Brown' then daily_total else 0 end) as DailyBrownNumbers,
   sum(case when category = 'Brown' then weekly_quota else 0 end) as WeeklyBrownNumbers,
   CURRENT_DATE as DATE_OF_REPORT
from dailyRecords
  where date_of_report >= current_date
group by employee
```

which reads from that table for the daily records and that's what I need still, but I want to add a sum for daily_total based on those days of the week if possible.

Can this be done with DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dayofweek function. SQL gets all records starting from Sunday including current date. Second column "DailyBrownNumbers" uses case statement to restrict totals to current date records. Third column "WeeklyTotal" has totals for all records from Sunday.

```
SELECT employee,
sum(case when category = 'Brown' and  date_of_report >=  current date 
       then daily_total 
       else 0 end) as DailyBrownNumbers,
sum(case when category = 'Brown' 
       then daily_total 
       else 0 end) as WeeklyTotal,
sum(case when category = 'Brown' 
       then weekly_quota 
    else 0 end) as WeeklyBrownNumbers,
CURRENT_DATE as DATE_OF_REPORT
from dailyRecords
where date_of_report >= ( current date - ( dayofweek(current date) - 1 ) days )
group by employee
```

Comment: So will this work when it runs every night? So if it runs Tuesday it needs sunday and monday, but if it runs friday it needs sunday,monday,tues,wed,and thurs

Comment: SQL will include all records starting from Sunday. Tuesday run includes records from Sunday, Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: To exclude current date records from weekly totals, add condition "date_ of_report < current date" to case statement for weekly totals

Comment: No I definitely do want current date included because it runs at the end of the day inclusively. But it's automated so I just want to make sure that any day it runs will include records for each day from the most recent sunday

Comment: SQL gets all records starting from most recent sunday including current date, you can change case statement depending on your requriements.

Comment: ok I think I see, but there may have been miscommunication. I still want the daily and weekly columns above to be based on today, I just want an extra column that gives me a sum of all daily totals for the week

Comment: so something like this as a new column ```sum(case when date_of_report >= ( current date - ( dayofweek(current date) - 1 ) days ) then sum(daily_total) end) as dailyTotalWeek,```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198750/discussion-between-satya-and-tom-n).