# DB2/SQL aggregates with preceeding weekdays

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query that currently gets daily records against a weekly number from a prepopulated table:

```
   SELECT Employee,
          sum(case when category = 'Shirts' then daily_total else 0 end) as Shirts_DAILY,
          sum(case when category = 'Shirts' then weekly_quota else 0 end) as Shirts_QUOTA, -- this is a static column, this number is the same for every record
          sum(case when category = 'Shoes' then daily_total else 0 end) as Shoes_DAILY,
          sum(case when category = 'Shoes' then weekly_quota else 0 end) as Shoes_QUOTA, -- this is a static column, this number is the same for every record
          CURRENT_DATE as DATE_OF_REPORT
   from SalesNumbers
   where date_of_report >= current_date
   group by Employee;
```

This runs in a script nightly and returns records like this:

```
   Employee   |   shirts_DAILY   |   shirts_QUOTA   |   Shoes_DAILY   |   Shoes_QUOTA   |   DATE_OF_REPORT
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   123                15                  75                14                85              2019-08-30
```

That's the record from last Friday Night's report. I'm trying to figure out a way to add a column for each category that would take the sum of daily totals (shirts_DAILY, shoes_DAILY) for each category on preceding weekdays (running sunday through saturday as a week) and divide by that category's quota (shirts_QUOTA, shoes_QUOTA).

For example, here are records from sunday through thursday

```
   Employee   |   shirts_DAILY   |   shirts_QUOTA   |   Shoes_DAILY   |   Shoes_QUOTA   |   DATE_OF_REPORT
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   123                15                 75                16                85              2019-08-25
   123                4                  75                2                 85              2019-08-26
   123                8                  75                6                 85              2019-08-27
   123                2                  75                8                 85              2019-08-28
   123                15                 75                14                85              2019-08-29
```

With my new change, I would want Friday night's record to take the sum of sunday through thursday's daily records and divide by the quota (including friday's daily in the sum)

Friday night's record with new column:

```
   Employee   |   shirts_DAILY   |   shirts_QUOTA   |   shirtsPercent   |   Shoes_DAILY   |   Shoes_QUOTA   |   shoesPercent   |   DATE_OF_REPORT
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   123                2                 75                    61.3               7                85              62.4                2019-08-30
```

So friday's run added `15,4,8,2,15,2` for the shirts for 46/75 and `7,14,8,6,2,16` for shoes for 53/85. So the daily sum of each for the preceding week, including present day daily totals, if that makes sense.

What is the best way for me to achieve this?

Comment: Check my answer to your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726952/using-days-of-the-week-for-aggregates-in-db2. It should not be difficult to calculate percentage after getting weekly totals. Since weekly quota is repeated in every record, use current day records  only for weekly quota total.

Comment: It still didn't seem to work as I expected, are you saying your answer should achieve this result though?

Comment: No. You have to build upon my answer. My SQL gives daily  totals, weekly totals. For weekly quota, you have to use current day records only to get weekly quota total as weekly quota is repeated in every record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT Employee,
    sum(case when category = 'Shirts' and  date_of_report >=  current date then 
        daily_total else 0 end) as Shirts_DAILY,
    sum(case when category = 'Shirts' and  date_of_report >=  current date then
       weekly_quota else 0 end) as Shirts_QUOTA,
    ( sum(case when category = 'Shirts' then 
        daily_total else 0 end) * 100 ) /
    ( sum(case when category = 'Shirts' and  date_of_report >=  current date then
       weekly_quota else 0 end) ) as Shirts_PERCENT,
    CURRENT_DATE as DATE_OF_REPORT
    from SalesNumbers
    where date_of_report >= ( current date - ( dayofweek(current date) - 1 ) days )
    group by Employee
```

Comment: AH, I see now. I fixed it up a bit after this answer and I think I have what I need. Sorry for the miscommunication, but thank you for your time and answers!